# Bigendian/Littleendian confusion

Tags: c++

i am working on the legacy code, which is written for ipv4. Now i have added the similar code for ipv6. i have tried and tested on host machine..but i have concern whether it will work on the powerpc , because of endianness...the code is to extract the ip header from the incoming stream and compress it..any comments will be helpful

```
class st_ipv6
{
  //==================================================================================================
public:
  //==================================================================================================

#ifdef _BIG_ENDIAN
  uint32  version:4;              // version 
  uint32  trafficclass:8;         // header length 
  uint32  flowlabel:20;           // flow label
#else
  uint32  trafficclass_1:4;
  uint32  version:4;              // version 
  uint32  flowlabel_1:4; 
  uint32  trafficclass_2:4;         // traffic class
  uint32  flowlabel_2:4;           // flow label 
  uint32  flowlabel_3:4;           // flow label 
  uint32  flowlabel_4:4;           // flow label 
  uint32  flowlabel_5:4;           // flow label 
#endif
  uint16  payloadlength;          // payload length
  uint8   nextheader;             // next header
  uint8   hoplimit;               // hop limit
  uint32  sourceaddress[4];       // source address 
  uint32  destinationaddress[4];  // destination address 




#ifdef _BIG_ENDIAN
  //**********************************************************************************************
  //* Description:
  /**  Specify/Return IPv6 Version
  */
  //**********************************************************************************************
  inline void setVersion(uint8 ubyVersion)
  {
    version = ubyVersion;
  }
  inline uint8 getVersion()
  {
    return version;
  }
```

Comment: I never saw anything like that, what is the purpose of all this ':' ?

Comment: @Ubiquité It's called bitfields http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Comment: Can you please post a specific question? If you have concerns, why not test it?

Comment: @Philipp: My concern is , whether this will work for the power pc. While running on windows, i see that endianess at nibble level. So i had to change my get and set functions, accordingly..now the concern whether the get and set functions for all the fields will work on the power pc too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitfields and portability are generally a nightmare.  It is usually better to use and/or/shift.

See e.g. below.

As long as you call hton*()/ntoh*() on the various integers as you read/write them you will (hopefully) have no problems.

I'd also write the rest of the accessors and make the data fields private.

```
class st_ipv6
{
public:
    uint32 version_info;
    uint16 payloadlength;          
    uint8  nextheader;             
    uint8  hoplimit;               
    uint32 sourceaddress[4];       
    uint32 destinationaddress[4]; 

    uint8 GetVersion() 
    { 
        return version_info & 0xF; 
    }
    void  SetVersion(uint8 v) 
    {
        version_info = (version_info & ~0xF) | (v & 0xF);
    }
    uint8 GetTrafficClass() 
    { 
        return (version_info & 0xFF0)>>4; 
    }
    void  SetTrafficClass(uint8 c) 
    {
        version_info = (version_info & ~0xFF0) | ((c & 0xFF) << 4);
    }
    uint32 GetFlowLabel() 
    { 
        return (version_info & 0xFFFFF000)>>12; 
    }
    void  SetFlowLabel(uint32 f) 
    {
        version_info = (version_info & ~0xFFFFF000) | ((f & 0xFFFFF) << 12);
    }
};
```

Comment: @ Michael : thankyou for the info. just to clarify. so are you suggesting, i need call hton and ntoh functions as wrapper to get and set functions ?

Comment: @user434250 - no.  We transmit data in "network" format but we store it locally in "host" (a.k.a. "local") format. 
When we receive data we use ntoh to convert it to local format and use it in local format.  When we want to transmit it, we use hton to convert it to network format.

Comment: @user434250 - it sounds odd, but C++ knows about local bit ordering and those get/set functions will work as long as the data is in local format, no matter what "local" actually is.  (assuming they are correct in the first place).  "x&1" will give you the least significant bit, no matter where the bit is physically stored in memory.  "x&(1<<31)" will give the most significant bit (of an uint32).  The same is **NOT** true for bitfields.

Comment: currently i am typecasting the input stream to st_ipv6 class..and call the set and get functions on the same stream

Comment: I guess you can incorporate hton/ntoh in the get/set routines, but be careful.  Particularly with the Set routines.  Maybe you can have a GetVersionInfo() { return ntoh(version_info); } and SerVersionInfo(uint32 vi) { version_info = hton(vi); }.  Then GetVersion() would return "GetVersionInfo() & 0xF"

Comment: thankyou, this clarifies a lot. so i think i need to do the same for other fields too, unless they are one byte.

Comment: @user434250 - yes, you would.

Comment: thanks a lot Michael. Based on inputs i wrote a simple version of the function and tried to do the basic test and it looks ok for the version fields. My program looks like this. Only concern now is, when we have array of uint32's like src and dst address ...

Comment: I think you call hton/ntoh for each element when get/set ing them

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a `struct` rather a `class` as things like RTTI could insert *extra* things in the memory layout.

and I think this should be sufficient

```
#ifdef _BIG_ENDIAN
  uint32  version:4;              // version 
  uint32  trafficclass:8;         // header length 
  uint32  flowlabel:20;           // flow label
#else
  uint32  flowlabel:20;           // flow label
  uint32  trafficclass:8;         // header length 
  uint32  version:4;              // version 
#endif
```

...but you should `ntohl(flowlabel)` when reading the flowlabel and `htonl(flowlabel)` when setting it.

Comment: No, a class is essentially the same as a struct.

Comment: Even if you enable RTTI in the compiler? or have virtual methods? My understanding is that a vtab is inserted shifting everything...

Comment: @epatel: sorry for my basic question, but can this function be generic across the platforms ? also whatabout the compiler interpretation..also i tried to extract the fields on windows host where the order of reading for nibble was different..

Comment: @epatel: Virtual functions and virtual base classes can (and do) take additional space, but that is not related to `struct` vs. `class`. Classes declared with `struct` can have virtual members or base classes as well. As long as the class has no virtual members or base classes and all data members have the same access control, it can be used just like a C struct in most cases.

Comment: @user434250 sorry, don't know about all platforms. But this was the method we used when porting old legacy SGI compiler code to intel (Windows Visual Studio and Linux GNU tools). Maybe there is more to check look out for, that I don't know now. But it's an interesting problem. Another completely different method is to make a bitbuffer class that you stuff and extract from which like a buffer put in (and extract) each field, ie `bitbuffer << myNibble << myInteger`. This method I believe could work on more platform not depending on compiler interpretations.

Comment: @Philipp so what did I write/recommend? Aren't you just explaining something that...I was saying in the first place?

Comment: @epatel You wrote "I would recommend using a struct rather a class as things like RTTI could insert extra things in the memory layout." which is not correct since the memory layout of a class does not depend on whether it has been defined using `struct` or `class`.

Comment: @Philipp you may be right technically, but if we throw all conventions out the window we haven't learnt anything I'd say. I'd be more careful to change a struct than a class any day. I have never seen anyone use a virtual method in a struct, and if I saw one I'd have a long talk with that person to hear what was the reason. One can do a lot of things in C++, but you shouldn't do everything. My notion is more that `struct` is closer to C and are less prone to be messed around by the compiler than `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with different compilers and using bitfields. Some compilers start the bitfield at the high bit and work downward while others work from the low bit.  You are better off doing the masking from the raw bytes yourself unless you test carefully across the different compilers you are using.

Comment: yes i.e my concern,whether this will work for the power pc. While running on windows, i see that endianess at nibble level. So i had to change my get and set functions, accordingly..now the concern whether the get and set functions for all the fields will work on the power pc too

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot Michael. Based on inputs i wrote a simple version of the function and tried to do the basic test and it looks ok for the version fields. My program looks like this. Only concern now is, when we have array of uint32's like src and dst address

class ip_v6{

public:
   uint32 version_info;
   uint16 payload_len;
   uint8 next_header;
   uint8 hop_limit;
   uint32 src_addr[4];
   uint32 dst_addr[4];

uint32 GetVersionInfo()
   {
      return ( ntohl(version_info));
   }

void SetVersionInfo(uint32 vinfo)
   {
      version_info = htonl(vinfo);
   }

uint8 GetVersion() 
   { 
      return ( ( (GetVersionInfo() )& (0xf0000000)) >> 28); 
   }

void  SetVersion(uint8 v) 
   {
      SetVersionInfo( ( GetVersionInfo() & 0x0fffffff ) | (v<<28));
   }

uint8 GetTrafficClass() 
   { 
      return ( ( (GetVersionInfo() )& (0x0ff00000)) >> 20); 
   }

void  SetTrafficClass(uint8 c) 
   {
      SetVersionInfo( (GetVersionInfo() & 0xf00fffff) |(c<<20 )) ;
   }

uint32 GetFlowLabel() 
   { 
      return ( (GetVersionInfo() )& (0x000fffff)) ;
   }

void  SetFlowLabel(uint32 f) 
   {
      SetVersionInfo( (GetVersionInfo() & 0xfff00000) |(f ) );
   }
};

Comment: I haven't checked that all the bit twiddling is correct, but that is certainly the right approach (IMHO).

Comment: thanks a lot Michael. yes, it is very much logical approach . i was going in line with the legacy ipv4 code and biased by that approach.